Is it possible to limit changes to a GCP Organization IAM Policy?
We've experienced an incident where a user was using Terraform against GCP to edit the organization policy (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_organization_iam). They mistakenly used google_organization_iam_policy instead of google_organization_iam_member, which resulted in the loss of the whole organization policy.
We had to manually recreate the policy to remediate this.
Is it possible to limit either with a deny policy or a specific change in the configuration to not allow destructive operations against the organization policy? We want to still allow some superadmins to make any changes, but we don't want all the superadmins to have the ability of removing users from the policy.

Does the Terraform SA or the user need to have that level of permissions?
Also, this usually should go through a PR process where somebody reviews the code that will be deployed.
You can create custom organisational policies as stated here but I'm more in favour of stablishing better permissions for the SA and CICD process, as you mentioned that tasks like this should be allowed.

The problem that we have is that some developers have org-wide permissions since they work on tools that cover the whole org in GCP. So even if the change goes via a stricter PR/CICD process, you can still have those changes.
Alternatively, you can have an SA that has enough permissions to do that and that would force you to go through that PR process in order to run it. That's a possibility.
